# GTK scroll to newly added child in a container

Tags: scrollbar, gtk, vala, gtk3

I have an application that will add a `Widget` to an `HBox`, which is contained in a `ScrolledWindow`.  When a `Widget` is added, I would like the parent `ScrolledWindow` to scroll to the right, where the newly added `Widget` is.  Adding the widget works just fine, my problem is:

**How can I make the ScrolledWindow move when a child is added?**

My Vala code looks something like:

```
private void addView() {
    var widget = this.createWidget();

    this.box.pack_start(widget);                   // this.box is a HBox
    widget.show_all();

    var adj = this.parent_win.get_hadjustment();   //  parent_win is a ScrolledWindow
    adj.set_value(adj.get_upper());
}
```

The behavior I am getting now is the adjustment will work every other double click (what signals all this).  I would like for the adjustment to occur on every double click.

**update** I have seen this: [Gtk, How to scroll at bottom of viewport list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681483/gtk-how-to-scroll-at-bottom-of-viewport-list) , but there is no real definitive answer given.  you mean to tell me i have to set a 1 sec timeout to scroll ?

Comment: This is very unclear: "The behavior I am getting now is the adjustment will work every other double click (what signals all this). I would like for the adjustment to occur on every double click."
Can you please rephrase?

Comment: @lethalman, sorry for any confusion.  I added a timeout per the link I posted in the Update.  The scrolling works as expected now (callback function moves it after 800 ms).  I am sure this is not the idiomatic way though - How can I "hook" into the "we are adding something to this container" signal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an idle callback instead of a timeout, and use the GtkContainer::add signal to get notified when a new child is added (http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/unstable/GtkContainer.html#GtkContainer-add).